# Binding view with butterknife on android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

Tags: android, android-adapter, autocompletetextview, android-inflate, butterknife

I created an class that extends RecyclerView.Adapter.

I'm using as layout the *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1*.

On my ViewHolder, I was trying to map it's TextView *text1* on a TextView variable, using this:

```
myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

This works like a charm, but I'm also using butterknife, and as far as I searched, I cant pass android.R.id.text1 anywhere.

What I tryed so far:

```
@BindView(android.R.id.text1)
TextView myTextView;
```

and also, on the constructor of my ViewHolder:

```
private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    myTextView = ButterKnife.findById(itemView, android.R.id.text1);
}
```

Is there a way to make it work with ButterKnife?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to pass the holder view which contains that text with id
like this:

```
@BindView(android.R.id.text1)
TextView myTextView;
private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
}
```

Comment: My friend, it does work u.u
I'm sorry for losing your time with such a unecessary answer.
Thanks for your help

Comment: It did my friend, thanks :D But... I swear I tried this before. What I did wrong is what I don't know ._.

Comment: And I was using the  ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView); on the constructor before, btw. The problem I was getting was on the @BindView.